# Numpy array remove duplicates non-order specific with additional element priority

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array which looks like this:

```
[['Apple' 'Banana' 'A']
 ['Banana' 'Apple' 'A']
 ['Banana' 'Apple' 'B']
 ['Banana' 'Apple' 'Z']
 ['Pear' 'Apple' 'Z']
 ['Apple' 'Pear' 'A']
 ['Apple' 'Orange' 'Z']]
```

I would like to first remove dups regardless of the order of elements. To appear as:

```
[['Apple' 'Banana' 'A']
 ['Banana' 'Apple' 'B']
 ['Banana' 'Apple' 'Z']
 ['Pear' 'Apple' 'Z']
 ['Apple' 'Pear' 'A']
 ['Apple' 'Orange' 'Z']]
```

Removed:  ['Banana' 'Apple' 'A']

Then remove all 'Z' elements when 'A' or 'B' element are present:

```
[['Apple' 'Banana' 'A']
 ['Banana' 'Apple' 'B']
 ['Apple' 'Pear' 'A']
 ['Apple' 'Orange' 'Z']]
```

Not necessary to maintain row order. If it can be done in 1 step that is even better. Thanks!

Comment: So, what *exactly* are your arrays like? Those look like invalid *list literals*. Could you post a reproducible example? Are these object `dtype` arrays containing strings? (If that is the case, you probably *should just use Python lists*). Or are they some form of structured array? What ever you are trying to do here, though, it seems that a `numpy.ndarray` is not the right data structure...

Comment: And what have you tried to solve this problem? This is certainly not a "write my code for me" website. Please look at [ask] and how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I am just trying to get a better understanding. I apologize if I offended someone. Yes, the dtype contains strings. The below solution seemed to be what I was trying to work through. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below, `a` is your data array:

```
[list(k) + v for k, v in {tuple(sorted(set(x[:2]))) : [x[2]] for x in a}.items()]
```

However, from your question it is not clear in which order items should be removed. For example you say: *"Removed: ['Banana' 'Apple' 'A']. Then remove all 'Z' elements when 'A' or 'B' element are present..."* There appears no logic in which order items are removed: A, Z, B, ... So, my code removes items in an arbitrary order.

Comment: Order would be cool to understand too, but this is definitely cleaner than what I had initially tried. Thanks!

Comment: @user2390954 It would have been nice if you would up-vote this answer if it solved your issue AND if you actually have tried something, you should have posted your code in your question as others have mentioned. "Order would be cool to understand too, ..." - do you mean for me or for you? I tried but I could not based on the details that you have provided. However, if you do understand the order, edit your question, provide a better description of the logic, and maybe someone will figure out the coding aspect for you.

Comment: I tried to vote it up and very much appreciate your time, but it said I don't have enough rep to vote. I definitely meant that it would be good for me to understand as I'm sure you probably already do. For instance if order did matter then how would I choose to eliminate 1: ['Apple' 'Banana' 'A']  instead of 2: ['Banana' 'Apple' 'A']?

Comment: @user2390954 You need to understand how the proposed solution works and then you will understand that if ordering is important - you will have to sort elements of the array ``a`` in an order that you need before proceeding with this solution. NOTE: In my previous messages I was referring to ordering by last key in your array ('A', 'B', etc.) - not by ordering inside the pairs of words.